# Why can't I increment score by 2?

Tags: android-studio, android-sharedpreferences

I have no idea how can you not understand such an easy task, but to summerise up everything:

> My main point is to increment score by 1 everytime button is clicked(Completed).
>   I want to change the incrementation, instead incrementing score by 1,
>   I want to increment score by 2 after upgrade button is clicked.

Goal:
{MainActivity: You click on a button, score increases by 1. UpgradeActivity: You click on a button, the increment is changed, and the score immediately increases by 2. I can't make it to increase by 2, instead by one.}

In app score I saved using `SharedPreference`, MainActivity.java:

```
public void button(View view) {

    mScore++;

    SharedPreferences myScore = getSharedPreferences("Symbols", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myScore.edit();
    editor.putInt("mScore", mScore);
    editor.commit();

    score.setText("Symbols: " + mScore);
}
```

UpgradeActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upgrade);

    score = findViewById(R.id.score);

    SharedPreferences myScore = this.getSharedPreferences("Symbols", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mScore = myScore.getInt("mScore", 0);

    score.setText("Symbols: " + mScore);
}

public void upgrade(View view) {

    if(mScore>=200){

        SharedPreferences myScore = this.getSharedPreferences("Symbols", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mScore = myScore.getInt("mScore", 0);

        mScore += 2;

        score.setText("Symbols: " + mScore);

        onResume();


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }


}
```

}

My whole point doesn't work. It still adds +1, so probably something wrong is with my UpgradeActivity or upgrade button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear to me, and I don't know what behavior you actually want here.

Comment: MainActivity: You click on a button, score increases by 1.                                                  UpgradeActivity: You click on a button, the increment is changed, and the score immediately increases by 2.   I can't make it to increase by 2, instead by one.

Comment: `if(mScore>=200)` ... you are checking the value of `mScore` but then you reassign it inside the `if` block.  That logic doesn't look correct to me.e

Comment: Should I use For loop?

Comment: The current logic for your `upgrade` method is that if the score is greater than 200, then you increment it by 2, otherwise you jump to the main activity.  Is this what you intend to do?

Comment: Nooo, I want to increment by 2 every time the button is clicked in the MainActivity. The UpgradeActivity is used to change the incrementation, from 1 to 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My main point is to increment score by 1 everytime button is clicked(Completed). I want to change the incrementation, instead incrementing score by 1, I want to increment score by 2 after upgrade button is clicked.  Whats so hard to understand?

Comment: Huh I reallu can't change the incrementation.. Tried while loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see from your code, your MainActivity here will always +1 due to `mScore++`

maybe change it to

```
int increment = 1;

public void button(View view) {

    mScore = mScore + increment;

    SharedPreferences myScore = getSharedPreferences("Symbols", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myScore.edit();
    editor.putInt("mScore", mScore);
    editor.commit();

    score.setText("Symbols: " + mScore);
}
```

then

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, UpgradeActivity.class), 1)
```

in UpgradeActivity.class

```
public void upgrade(View view) {

    if(mScore>=200){
       setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }

    onBackPressed();
}
```

then in MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           increment = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

hope this answer you question / or will give you some ideas...

Comment: Where should I place `startActivityForResult(newIntent(this, UpgradeActivity.class), 1);` in my code ? This line stands for..?

Comment: startActivityForResult is like startActivity but it expect to return something. Use it at the point you want to go to UpgradeActivity.class

Comment: Thanks man! Somehow, starActiviryForResult code line doesnt work, but I'll try to fix it